# Check database every second

Tags: performance, jpa

I was wondering if I can check the database every second to get the fields which are older than the current date.

```
select o from Entity as o where o.date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

For performance, it is not good at all isn't it ? Is there any way to do otherwise ?

I am building a JSF webapp using CDI and EJB throught JPA persistence.

More details :

I have set a list of action in a table called "Actions". These actions has to be execute when the Actions.fieldDate is equals to the current date.

I am currently using Java EE7 with the last JDK 8.

Comment: what version of Java EE are you using?

Comment: It's hard to say something is good or not good for performance without detailed context and testing, but generally speaking, `check the database every second` and `performance` don't go together.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  This is an XY problem.  If you tell us the actual problem you are trying to solve, we can help solve it, rather than judge your solution.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: By the way, your query does the opposite of what you are asking about.  It finds fields which are *newer* than the current date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use materialized view

> This enables much more efficient access, at the cost of some data
>   being potentially out-of-date. It is most useful in data warehousing
>   scenarios, where frequent queries of the actual base tables can be
>   expensive. - wikepedia

Answer (score 0):

A lot will depend on how frequently entries are made to your Actions table and what timestamp they could hold. For example, if you expect the entries to be made in advance, say minimum 5 mins before the actions could be executed, then you could reduce your read frequency, either by a materialized view with a ttl of 5 mins or some other caching mechanism.

Alternatively, you could have a trigger on your actions table that tells you about a new row insertion, you then read it and schedule it accordingly.